# How can i install OpenPop.NET on my visual studio 2012 pro using the NuGet package manager console?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, openpop

I have the console opened at the bottom and inside i type:

Install-Package OpenPop.NET that's what they say to type in the website:

[OpenPop.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenPop.NET/)

I typed it in the console but i'm getting error:

Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package OpenPop.NET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Do i need to download something else ?

Comment: So, did you have a solution open when you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current environment doesn't have a solution open.

You must start with a solution to add a package to it. You add NuGet packages to solutions, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly states that you need to have a solution open. First open a solution with a project, then try to install the package.